# How best can I produce a cartesian product with the different columns of a same table?

Tags: t-sql, self-join, cross-join

Suppose I do have a table `ManjoloHigh` that holds the following columns: `Firstname, Surname, Age, Gender, Village`, and you're required to produce a cartesian product based on the following these two columns: `Village, Firstname`.

What is the best way to produce a cartesian product in T-SQL?

Comment: What does it mean to "produce a Cartesian product based on columns"? Use enough words & sentences to clearly say what you mean. What language are you using? SQL? R? If it's relational algebra then give a reference to your textbook because there are many variants. Read & act on [mcve] (give example input & output) & hits googling 'stackexchange homework' (show parts you can do).

Comment: @philipxy You're absolutely right, but  the fact that I didn't mention maybe is the wrong part. Anyway, it's t-sql. This question was asked by someone he didn't mention the language too, and then the question was left unattended. So I decided to re-ask it and provide the solution to it. Thanks, expect something improved next time.

Comment: What is the original post? Why didn't you just answer it? Please don't re-ask questions. If it is not clear edit it. Use tags for languages. This is still not clear, it is not helpful.

Comment: @philipxy I would prefer to say thanks, I don't know how to edit someone's text. Anyway appreciate it none is 100% perfect I'm still studying I don't know all the techniques  needed, I believe you once experienced the same before you became who are today. Thank you.

Comment: Click on "edit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to retreive a set of unique possible combinations of the values in given columns.

You could either explode your resultset by creating a huge cartensian product, followed by `DISTINCT`, like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT V.Village, F.Firstname 
FROM MANJOLOHIGH AS V 
CROSS JOIN MANJOLOHIGH AS F
```

Or you could create subsets of the unique values in every column and cross join these, like so:

```
SELECT V.Village, F.Firstname 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Village FROM MANJOLOHIGH) AS V 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Firstname FROM MANJOLOHIGH) AS F
```

Given the fact that you are talking about five columns, I'd strongly suggest the latter.
Given a table of 1000 records, the first resultset would result in 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 records, before `DISTINCT` is applied.

Comment: Wow! You guys you making my skills go deeper. What else could I have done without your support?, Oh, my thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By naming the columns and aliasing the same table differently meet the requirements of producing a Cartesian product, like this:

```
SELECT V.Village, F.Firstname 
FROM MANJOLOHIGH AS V 
CROSS JOIN MANJOLOHIGH AS F;
```

This code will produce a resultset of `V.Village` rows multiplied by `F.Firstname` rows.

Comment: Not true, this will create a cartesian product of all records. You'd need to use a `(SELECT DISTINCT Village FROM MANJOLOHIGH) AS v` subquery or something like that. A `DISTINCT` on your whole query would also work.

Comment: @Zohar Peled thanks, but I've tried it on 2 columns in a table with 12 columns. Each column had 91 rows and the resultset was 8281 rows not including other columns. Thanks for being a good teacher.

Comment: @Zohar Peled I don't know how far I would have gone without you guys, your support makes my day everyday, I strongly appreciate your efforts. You've been always by my side trying by all means to make me understand, your expagorations are too pellucid and easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

@Lanceleazol, see the modified below: You will need a distict to prevent double entries appearing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT V.Village, F.Firstname 
FROM MANJOLOHIGH AS V 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT F.Firstname 
                FROM
                 MANJOLOHIGH AS F) F
```

Comment: it's so pretty good to have you. Thanks for the code, it is vividly understandable.